# Почему при вводе символа в input в результат выводится на символ меньше?

Tags: javascript

Я изучаю нативный js и хочу вывести из input в тег p value но выводится на символ меньше, где ошибка ?

```js
document.getElementById('in').onkeypress = function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById('in').value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('in').addEventListener("input", function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById('in').value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: я запутался ... чей ответ лучше

Comment: @Nikita, мой вариант с задержкой работает, этот шустрее. Но возможно и от браузера зависит, у меня Chrome

Comment: @Nikita, но вот не знаю касается ли этого кода, но возможна не совместимость старых IE с input, приведу тебе одну копипасту: Обратим внимание – весь этот «танец с бубном» нужен только для поддержки IE8-, в которых не поддерживается oninput и IE9, где oninput не работает при удалении.

Answer (score 3):

Замени onkeypress на onkeyup

```js
document.getElementById('in').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById('in').value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: круто ... через 11 минут смогу только принять ответ ... а какая у них разница ?

Comment: @Nikita, на английском копипаста понятна будет? In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.